# Finding an unknown CSS rule by its properties

Tags: css

Is there a way to find a rule existing in the given page's stylesheets by its CSS properties? I'll take a browser plugin, fancy javascript, or even an IDE feature.

**Consider this scenario:** maintaining/making changes to a legacy site when there is no reason (or budget) to have its codebase re-factored. Now multiply that by roughly a hundred such individual websites :)

It's too tempting to start coding "the right way" for any ad-hoc change request, no matter how small, and introduce "proper" semantic classes, tasteful inheritance and googly naming conventions. In reality, of course, all this does without proper re-factoring is pollute the stylesheet until the next dev comes along and repeats the process. I'd rather act as more of a *do no harm* developer when given a choice.

Let's say new build requires something fairly basic, like thumbnail images floated left with some margin around them. You look at the css files but can't find anything *specific* like `.teaser-thumbnail` (and give up after failing to see any logic in the first 200 rules). Still, there is a good chance that there is already a rule serving a similar purpose, or perhaps some helper classes. Yet there is no straightforward way to locate these rules and you wouldn't necessarily recognize their purpose by name.

Comment: I'd consider creating my own classes prefixed with my identifier. The existing classes *might* possess an attribute I'm looking for but it would very likely be combined with several other settings that I don't want.

Comment: I'm 70% sure browsers have an API to inspect CSS definitions. Have you tried poking around MDN?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [Firefox' Web Developer plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), go to `CSS` - `View CSS`.
This will display all available CSS (from multiple files) on one very long page. Then you can search for the properties that you want to apply and see if you can find any suitable classes.

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm doing now, but it's way too manual (you're right about it being *one very long page* :) If I'm looking for an existing style that adds spacing at the bottom of an element, I can't just search for `margin-bottom` in that list - the property is too common, I don't know if the desired class used a shorthand variant etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking is how to add css attributes onto existing selectors for a given element if they exist?  If that's the case:

1. Open site in Chrome
2. Right click element > Inspect Element
3. Look at right column `Styles` section and see all selectors that apply to the given element.

Comment: I use this feature daily while developing.  This is especially helpful when someone hands you a site and says "move that there" or "change this color."  You just inspect the element, find the style, open the style sheet and perform a search for that class/id.  Easy does it, good answer DMoses.

Comment: No, that's not it; sorry if the original phrasing was misleading. I *don't* have an element on the page that already possesses properties I'm after, but rather I *might* have the necessary rules available in the stylesheet.